# Как работать со своей формой в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть файл шаблон страницы(page.php), в нём определённый скрипт обработки формы, но после отправки формы (action формы указывает на текущую страницу то есть _http://example.com/?page_id=1) после отправки данных в адресной строке ссылка остается текущей странице, но запрашивается index.php, как сделать чтобы при отправке формы я мог обрабатывать данные с файла page.php? Как вариант обработать данные в index.php и сделать редирект на страницу, но как-то не лучшее решение по-моему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил это следующим образом, создал в темы файл обработки формы, при отправке формы там добавляется скрытое поле в котором храниться ссылка на текущую страницу, после обработки данных делается редирект назад на странцу.

Comment: По такому же принципу реализуется авторизация в wordpress. В форме авторизации есть скрытое поле:
<input type="hidden" value="СТРАНИЦА_РЕДИРЕКТА" name="redirect_to">
Это нормально. Если не хотите редиректы, используйте ajax-запросы